# Post message with WWW::Mechanize for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: perl

I'm trying to post a message to a webpage but I can't figure out what the name of the form is?  I am trying www::mechanize but I would use another module if its a better method.  I am able to pull the authenticated page and see the current message posted.  I dumped the forms on the page so here is the output:

```
$VAR2 = bless( {
                 'default_charset' => 'UTF-8',
                 'enctype' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'accept_charset' => 'UNKNOWN',
                 'action' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://myffleague.football.cbssports.com/setup/commish-tools/messaging/edit-league-message')}, 'URI::http' ),
                 'method' => 'POST',
                 'attr' => {
                             'style' => 'display:inline',
                             'method' => 'post'
                           },
                 'inputs' => [
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => '1',
                                        'name' => 'dummy::form',
                                        'id' => 'dummy::form',
                                        'type' => 'hidden'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => 'form',
                                        'name' => 'form::form',
                                        'id' => 'form::form',
                                        'type' => 'hidden'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => 'U2FsdGVkX1_UaI-cThHnk4dukS_AYpTgYLwzWpW7wsoYNpHOMGPSzno0W5zhDRSt',
                                        'name' => 'form::_eid_',
                                        'id' => 'form::_eid_',
                                        'type' => 'hidden'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'value' => '<b>Weekly High Scorers:
                                                    Week 1  => Team 12
                                                   ',
                                        'name' => 'form::message',
                                        'class' => 'formText',
                                        'id' => 'message',
                                        'type' => 'textarea',
                                        'rows' => '10',
                                        'cols' => '60'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => '/setup',
                                        'name' => 'form::xurl',
                                        'id' => 'xurl',
                                        'type' => 'hidden'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => '   OK   ',
                                        'name' => '_submit',
                                        'class' => 'formButtonLg custombutton',
                                        'type' => 'submit'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::SubmitInput' )
                             ]
               }, 'HTML::Form' );
```

The value I'm trying to post is the high scorer of the week.  So here is the post I'm attempting.  I don't get an error, but the message doesn't change.  For this example its contained in '$msg'

```
$mech->form_name('form::message');
print Dumper($mech->forms());
$mech->field("value", $msg);
$mech->submit();
```

I'm adding this section after users requested more information from me.  this is the url i'm pulling, by supplying my userid and password I get the authenticated page back.  At that point I then use the same 'mech' object to post a message to the league.

```
my $url = "http://myffleague.football.cbssports.com/setup/commish-tools/messaging/edit-league-message?xurl=/setup";
my $username = "username";
my $password = "password";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_id('login_form');
$mech->field("userid", $username);
$mech->field("password", $password);
$mech->click;

my $msg = "Weekly High Scorers:\nWeek 1  => Team 12\nWeek 2  => Team 10";
$mech->field('form::message', $msg);
$mech->submit();
print "\n\nAll Good\n\n" if ($mech->success);
```

And here is the requested html from the site.  Its not the entire page, but the section where I need to post.  I used screenshot to create the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to the `field()` method is the name of the field you're setting. None of the fields in your form has the name "value". I think the name that you want is "form::message".

```
$mech->field('form::message', $msg);
$mech->submit();
```

Comment: I tried that but still no change.  Again, no error, but the message is still not updating.

Comment: How about a minimal, complete example of what you are doing?

Comment: I am posting a message to a website that will contain the weekly high scorers in our fantasy football league.  I did the edit manually in the 1st week and you can see above that the value for that week is embedded in the returned dumped forms.  So all I'm doing is trying to automate the posting of the high scorer each week, in this case, week 2 winner, but after the post is done it is still just showing week 1.  So the value contained in the variable $msg will be Weekly High Scorers:                Week 1  => Team 12           Week 2 => Team X

Comment: @JamesFinnegan: You should also remove the `$mech->form_name('form::message')` line. Your page doesn't have a form called "form::message" so it's certainly not doing anything useful and may be doing some harm.

Comment: @DaveCross, I  did Dave.  I used your exact example you posted but still nothing.

Comment: @JamesFinnegan: Then, as brian says, without a complete, runnable example, there's not a lot more we can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hey Dave, I added what I'm doing at the end of the post above.  I'm not sure if you can duplicate it as you have to authenticate to gain acccess.  But the forms are displayed above from the mech dump.

Comment: @JamesFinnegan Seeing the HTML of that form page would be useful. Perhaps you could use a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to share it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199585/discussion-between-james-finnegan-and-dave-cross).

Comment: I don't have pastebin and my company isn't allowing access to it.  I've not done attachments here so not sure where to go on this.

Comment: @DaveCross, I put an image of the html in the original question.  Not sure if this works for you.  Appreciate the time.